Find out if user name and database are matching | grep
I found that grep -w 'desired_string' should deliver just lines exactly desired_string, but not desired_string-22 or any variant.
What I need is a check if a certain Postgres database is owned by a certain user. So I tried things like
sudo --login -u postgres psql --command="\l" | grep -w  'database-name' | grep -w 'user-name'

but none of the variants I tried are working. Not even
sudo --login -u postgres psql --command="\l" | grep -w  "70-prod"

only delivers, 70-prod, but 70-prod-mod1 as well. I found many hit on this issue, but none seems to work with this psql command.
Does somebody have a good idea?
Thanks a lot in advance,
Wolf

Unfortunately your premise for grep -w is provably wrong:
echo 'desired_string-22' | grep -w 'desired_string'
desired_string-22

The -w flag is described in the documentation (see man grep) as,

Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words. The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non‐word constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or  followed  by  a  non‐word constituent  character.   Word‐constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,  and  the underscore.

In your example the - is considered a word separator, so while desired-string is a complete word, the phrase desired_string-22 contains two words desired_string and 22; consequently your word match desired_string succeeds.
So, let's try and achieve the desired result in another way.
Running psql -l here I get this output:
sudo -u postgres psql --command="\l"
                                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | ICU Locale | Locale Provider |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 |            | libc            |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)

I'm going to assume you want to match on the database name in the first column, and the username in the second.
db='template0'    # Replace with '70-prod' or appropriate
un='postgres'     # Replace with appropriate username

sudo --login -u postgres psql --command="\l" |
    awk -F'\\|' -v db="$db" -v un="$un" '{ gsub(" ", "") } $1==db && $2==un'

Example output from the basic database set I've shown:
template0|postgres|UTF8|en_GB.UTF-8|en_GB.UTF-8||libc|=c/postgres+

Notice that all spaces have been removed, and that | is the field separator.
If you don't actually need the output, but just want to use the result of the test (I assume you do, although that's not explicitly stated in the question) you can modify the awk so it can be used in a conditional:
db='template0'    # Replace with '70-prod' or appropriate
un='postgres'     # Replace with appropriate username

if
    sudo --login -u postgres psql --command="\l" |
    awk -F'\\|' -v db="$db" -v un="$un" 'BEGIN {ss=1} {gsub(" ", "")} $1==db && $2==un {ss=0} END {exit ss}'
then
    echo "Found a matching line" >&2
else
    echo "No matching line found" >&2
fi

You can, of course, query the schema directly:
db='template0'    # Replace with '70-prod' or appropriate
un='postgres'     # Replace with appropriate username
sql="   select pd.oid, pd.datname, pd.datdba, pa.rolname
        from pg_database pd
        join pg_authid pa on pa.oid = pd.datdba
        where pd.datname = :'db' and pa.rolname = :'un'
"
sudo -u postgres psql -v db="$db" -v un="$un" <<<"$sql"


grep with -w will not work in your case, as - is also considered a word separator.
sudo --login -u postgres psql --command="\l" | awk '$1=="exactdbmatch" && $3=="exactusermatch" {print $1, $3}'

The default field separator for awk is any consecutive run of whitespaces. That's why the delimiter | in PostgreSQL \l output is treated as the $2 value. If you want to get Owner in $2, you can modify the field separator.
Anyway, this hacky solution should do the job you want.
Don't forget to use double quotes around your database and username.
sudo --login -u postgres psql --command="\l" | awk '$1=="postgres" && $3=="postgres" {print $1, $3}'


@ChrisDavies Thanks for correcting me. Got something new to learn.

Thank you so much for your elaborate answers. To be honest, I ever avoided awk, so I'll first have to make myself familiar with it in order to make my adaptation. But this now is a good reason. (:

After some days with awk, I understood some very basics, but could find out how actually to make @ChrisDavies' solution work. I need to hand over the contents of variables für user and database, but something like  sudo --login -u postgres psql --command="\l" | awk '$1==var_database && $3==var_user {print $1, $3}'   didnt work. How could it?  Thanks for all your effort.

@herrdeh You've missed "" around your db and user names. If you will not have your db and user names within quotes, it will not return you your desired output.

@herrdeh if you want to use my solution, it shows exactly how to use it

Right. Learned that variables in awk do not have the $ sign. My wrong. But I still cannot make it work:
me@my-machine:~$ sudo --login -u postgres psql --command="\l" | grep 70-prod [sudo] Passwort für wd:   70-prod              | wolf     | UTF8     | en_US.utf8  | en_US.utf8  |   70-prod-eval01       | wd       | UTF8     | en_US.utf8  | en_US.utf8  |  me@my-machine:~$ ben=wolf me@my-machine:~$ db=70-prod me@my-machine:~$ echo $ben $db  wolf 70-prod me@my-machine:~$ sudo --login -u postgres psql --command="\l" | awk '$1=="db" && $3=="ben" {print $1, $3}' me@my-machine:~$ 

Sorry for this mess, unluckily I cannot edit it.

Right, learned that variables in awk do not have the $ sign. My wrong, thank you. But I still cannot make it work, command does not return resulting $1 and $3 contents. I think it's time to give up now; changing "-" to "_" with 'tr' might be easier.  Thanks for all the effort anyway!
